# To know the state of USB (Serial) connection (connected or not connected)

Tags: serial

```
if (Serial.available()) {
        digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
} else {
        digitalWrite(7, LOW);
}
```

It doesn't seem to be so simple.
My testing LED turns on when the USB connection with another program is established, but it doesn't turn off (LOW) when that program exits.

Comment: Cross posted on [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348533.0) and a [second time](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348613.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How about having the other program send data to Arduino and Arduino knowing the connection is lost when new data isn't received? I have no idea what Arduino code would do that but just an idea.

That sounds simple enough.

```C++
const unsigned long MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 10UL * 1000;  // 10 seconds

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  while (!Serial) ;  // wait for Serial to become active
  Serial.println ("Starting");

  }  // end of setup

unsigned long lastMessage;

void processInput ()
  {
  while (Serial.available ())
    {
    char c = Serial.read ();
    // do something with the data
    }  // end of while loop
  }  // end of processInput

void loop ()
  {
  if (Serial.available ())
    {
    lastMessage = millis ();  // remember when we last got input
    processInput ();  // now handle the input
    }  

  if (millis () - lastMessage >= MESSAGE_TIMEOUT)
    {
    // we don't seem to be receiving data  
    }

  }  // end of loop
```

Comment: And an issue on the Python side... http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/pyserial-serial-write-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is twofold.

Firstly, on Arduinos that don't have a direct USB connection, (i.e., boards like the Uno, Mega, etc that use a separate chip to manage the USB connection) you have no way of knowing if the USB is open or not.  That information simply isn't there. The main chip just receives UART serial data (*not* USB data) as it arrives and that is that.

Secondly, even on the boards that have a direct USB connection (Leonardo, etc) there is no *proper* way to know if the port has been opened or not.  The CDC/ACM protocol simply doesn't have that kind of information (a bit short sighted of them really).  The closest you can do is monitor the DTR and/or RTS signals that are encapsulated in the USB data stream.  It is down to the host operating system (and maybe even your own program) to exert those signals properly, so isn't foolproof even then.

To check the status of those lines in your sketch you can examine the *boolean operator* of the `Serial` object:

```
if (Serial) {
  // I am connected
} else {
  // I am not connected
}
```

But as I say that can only work on boards like the Leonard - the other indirect boards think they are always connected, since there is no such thing as a *connection* in UART terminology, only data.

Comment: How about having the other program send data to Arduino and Arduino knowing the connection is lost when new data isn't received? I have no idea what Arduino code would do that but just an idea.

Comment: That method is known as *keepalive*.

Comment: "method" as in a function, or technique? Any example somewhere?

Comment: Technique.  How you do it depends on what you are doing serial-wise at the moment.

Comment: I'm lighting a LED when there's a USB connection between a PC program ans Arduino.

Comment: That's very interesting. It doesn't give even the slightest hint what you are doing. Ask a new question. Describe your sex al data flow and protocol. Ask how you might best implement a keepalive system in it.

Comment: There's no need for a new question. This is a simple question, I need to know the state (connected/not connected) of USB connection between a PC program and Arduino and tell the state by flashing a LED. What more do you want? There's either an answer to the question or there isnt.

Comment: I have given you the answer to that. Now you are asking about how to work around the fact that there is no way of knowing. The amount of extra information you will have to provide in order to get an answer to that will change the current question beyond recognition and will invalidate this and any other answer. This is not open to discussion. If you want information about something other than what you asked then you ask another question providing *in detail* what has been asked for. Comments are for clarification of the existing question not for asking new ones.

Comment: There is no way of knowing? Then why did you say "That method is known as keepalive"? when I thought of some way? There either is no way or there is some way. Can you answer that, here or in a new post (which I feel will be marked s dublicate).

Comment: That has nothing to do with knowing if it is connected or not - it is merely a method of determining if the connection is alive and working. The two are very different and require completely different ways of thinking. Just ask the new question. I am not discussing this any more.

Comment: What is the difference between "connected" and "alive and working"? I'll need to know that to ask the question properly. Maybe I even asked the wrong question to begin with by using the wrong term.

Comment: The difference is the difference between "is" and "was". You know the term (keepalive) and what you need to tell us (your existing serial protocol, what your programs do and how that pertains to the serial).

Comment: "The difference is the difference between "is" and "was"". That wasnt clear at all...

Comment: Go ask the question.