# make Arduino tell when the Python program stops reading from the Serial (crash, etc)

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, python

Here's the Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
    int val = digitalRead(7);
    if (val == HIGH) {
        Serial.print("1");
    } else {
        Serial.print("0");    
    }
    Serial.println("");  // new line

}
```

Python code:

```
import time
import serial

# setup Arduino USB communication
try:
    arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)

except: # not connected/damaged
    pass

while True:
    if arduinoSerialData.inWaiting() > 0:
        datastr = arduinoSerialData.readline()
        print datastr
        time.sleep(1)
```

WHat I want to add is, if Python program exits, or crashes, let the Arduino know somehow. More specifically turn on a LED in pin 8.

Comment: You didn't provide the information you were asked for. What does your existing serial protocol consist of? How does your "program" operate? We need *DETAIL*!

Comment: And anyway, you just asked the *same* question, not the question you were told to ask!

Comment: possible duplicate of [know the state of USB (Serial) connection (coonected or not connected)](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16207/know-the-state-of-usb-serial-connection-coonected-or-not-connected)

Comment: You were told the exact terms to ask about, and the exact information that was required, neither of which you have given.  The question should have been more along the lines of "I have written a program in Python that does XXX.  It communicates with the Arduino using a protocol that consists of YYY, ZZZ, etc.  How can I implement keepalive in this situation?"

Comment: Majenko, I asked you what I needed to ask. You said to ask something I didn't understand what even meant and refused to explain so I'd know it is what I indeed need to ask. Give me a break.

Comment: I have just told you the exact words to use.  Fill in the blanks.

Comment: I'm not going to ask something without understanding what is it I'm asking. That's retarded.

Comment: What part of that question formatting do you not understand?

Comment: It's not about formatting, it's about the terminology, I asked you this already and you refused to listen.

Comment: WHAT terminology do you not understand?!

Comment: I told you already in the other thread and you replied with "Go ask the question". Take a chill pill.

Comment: I told you in that question WHAT to ask, yet you seem to have refused point blank. You also refuse point blank to tell me what it is you don't understand.  Is it the "Keepalive" you don't understand? "Protocol"? "Serial"? What? YOU suggested a concept. I gave it a name. Now you are saying you don't understand?!

Comment: I already said why I refused to ask what you wrote down for me to ask, and very clearly gave the reason why, which was that I didn't understand if that was what I needed to know. And I'm not refusing to tell what I didn't understand "point blank" now, it's just that the comment is still there, but fine, I'll repost here:  What is the difference between "connected" and "alive and working"? And then, "What does your existing serial protocol consist of?" What does that mean? "How does your "program" operate?" - what does this mean? Youre asking to post all that. I'm asking what you need exactly.

Comment: They are far from vague.  "What does your existing serial protocol consist of?" You have a serial connection. You must be sending data down it in some form.  The Keepalive will also be serial data. We NEED to know what data YOU are sending so we can determine what the best way of augmenting that with Keepalive messages would be. "How does your program operate?" What data does it consume or produce? If we need to CHANGE your protocol we NEED to know what that protocol has to support.

Comment: Some reading matter.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive

Comment: "The Keepalive will also be serial data", "What data does it consume or produce?" sorry but for me specifically this is pretty vague. At this point I can post my Arduino code and Python code. I'm not as experienced as you nor can I read your mind.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot be more explicit than that. If you are unable to describe what your program does then how are we going to know what it does unless it is only a handful of lines?

Comment: You have two programs. Let's call them A (Arduino) and P (Python).  WHAT does A send to P? WHAT does P send to A? WHEN does A send things to P? WHEN does P send things to A?

Comment: Okay, code it is then. Give me a minute to simplify the codes and post what each does (you already know though). I think you have the privillege to edit the title, right?

Comment: Cross posted on [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348533.0) and a [second time](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348613.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know if the connection has closed or not, you can only know if the connection *was* working at some point in the past.

Your communication protocol as shown is only *half duplex* (i.e., it's only one way - the Arduino sends to Python but never the other way around) which simplifies things somewhat.

There are a number of strategies you can employ in your case, and any number of them can be combined to create a system as robust (and complex) as you like.

First you would need to make your protocol *full duplex*.  This is, you need your Python program to be able to send information to the Arduino.  Since you aren't doing that at the moment the implementation of it can be in any way you like.

One method you can use is called [Keepalive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive).  In this system the Python program will periodically send an "I am here" message to the Arduino.  The Arduino receives these messages and remembers when the last one was (hint: use the `millis()` function).  If a message hasn't been received for more than a pre-defined timeout period the link is assumed to be dead.

Another method which is good if you are sending data very regularly from the Arduino to the Python program is to use a system of *acknowledgements*.  In this situation every bit of data sent to the Python program is followed by the Python replying with an "I got that" message.  If the Arduino doesn't get that response after sending its data within a certain timeout period (can be much shorter than for a keepalive timeout) then the link is assumed to be dead.

Wrapped around both these methods you can add an "I have arrived" and an "I am leaving" message.  These are sent by the Python program when it starts and just before it's about to exit so the Arduino knows when the link *should* be alive and when it *shouldn't*.  If it gets an "I am leaving" message then it knows that it shouldn't care whether it gets any acknowledgement or keepalive messages, so it doesn't need to think about timeouts. Only after it has received an "I have arrived" message should it start caring.

So for instance your protocol, with all these things implemented, might look like this (`>>` = message from Arduino to Python, `<<` is message from Python to Arduino):

```
>> 1
>> 1
>> 1
>> 0
>> 0
>> 1
<< A    - I have arrived
>> 1
<< Y    - Yes, I got that
>> 1
<< Y    - Yes, I got that
>> 0
<< Y    - Yes, I got that
<< K    - keepalive - we know the link is alive and working.
>> 0
<< Y    - Yes, I got that
>> 1
<< Y    - Yes, I got that
(Program crashes now.)
>> 1
*no Y received - assume connection is closed*
>> 1
... etc ...
```

In this instance the 0 and 1 are what you are sending at the moment.  A is an "I have **A**rrived" message, Y is a "**Y**es I got that" message, K is a "**K**eepalive" message, and if the program had exited cleanly an L would have been an "I am **L**eaving" message.

Keeping the messages simple (single characters) means it's really easy for the Arduino to parse those messages and work out what is going on.

There is a certain amount of balancing act to be performed when implementing your system between how often you are sending data and how long you are willing to wait for a valid response or message to flag the connection closed.

Expanding your existing example program to incorporate these messages might look like:

```
unsigned long lastKA = 0;
unsigned long lastSent = 0;
boolean isConnected = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {

    // Check the timeouts if we are connected
    if (isConnected) {

        // First check to see if the Keepalive timeout has passed
        if (millis() - laskKA > 5000) { // 5 second keepalive timeout)
            isConnected = false;
        }

        // If we have sent data...
        if (lastSent > 0) { 
            // ... check that we got a response in time
            if (millis() - lastSent > 100) { // 100ms Y timeout
                isConnected = false;
            }
        }

    }

    // If we are connected then send some data
    if (isConnected) {

        int val = digitalRead(7);
        if (val == HIGH) {
            Serial.print("1");
        } else {
            Serial.print("0");    
        }
        Serial.println("");  // new line

        // and set the timer for the response
        lastSent = millis();
    }

    // Now process incoming messages.
    if (Serial.available()) {
        int c = Serial.read();

        // If the message is an A then turn on the connection and
        // treat it as a Keepalive as well.
        if (c == 'A') { // Arrived
            isConnected = true;
            lastKA = millis();

        // If it's a Leaving message then turn off the connection.
        } else if (c == 'L') { // Leaving
            isConnected = false;

        // If it's a Keepalive then reset the timer.
        } else if (c == 'K') { // Keepalive
            lastKA = millis();

        // A Y acknowledgement will disable the sent timer.
        } else if (c == 'Y') { // Yes
            lastSent = 0; // Cancel the sent timer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is odd, `serial.Serial.write('1')` in Python doesn't seem to write anything to the buffer, `print serial.Serial.readline()` doesnt show what it wrote. Otherwise will work.