# Pyserial serial.write() doesn't work

Tags: serial, python

I need to communicate with an Arduino. When I use `serial.readline()` to read what Arduino has to say it works fine. But when I use`serial.write('something')` doesn't seem to do anything.

Interesting thing is that if I write the same code in the console or command-line, it works as expected...

Using Python 2.7.

Python code:

```
import serial
import time

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com6', 9600)
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    arduinoSerialData.write('AAA')
    arduinoSerialData.flush()
    sleep(0.5)
```

Arduino code:

```
void loop() {

if (Serial.readString().startsWith("AAA")) {
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
} else {
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
}

delay(500);
```

Again, Python code runs fine from the console, so no idea why this happens.

Comment: Your subject is `Pyserial serial.write() doesn't work` but you follow up by saying it `runs fine from the console`. So, the serial.write **does** in fact work. Try to stop using the words "doesn't work" and describe in more detail what is happening.

Comment: Cross posted on [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348533.0) and a [second time](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348613.0).

Comment: please append what you did that worked - so the steps you did in the 'console' -

Comment: i think that your `readString()` can't reliably get all three AAAs in one catch - you have to send them at the right moment - otherwise it will read only first or last part or something else...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with my raspberry pi, where sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't. I'm trying to send the sys.argv array, minus the first element, and display it on a screen, which I thought would be simple, but sometimes it will work and sometimes not. Code on the pi: import serial import sys ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600) args = str(' '.join(sys.argv[1:])) args = args.replace("'","") ser.write("test".encode()) print(args) Code on the arduino: String incomingByte; #include <LiquidCrystal.h> LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2); void setup() { lcd.begin(16, 2); //l

Comment: @voidUpdate, please delete your comment, it has nothing to do with the question that was asked, and nobody will answer it ... please post your own question instead

Answer (score 2):

Closely related to [To know the state of USB (Serial) connection (connected or not connected)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16207/know-the-state-of-usb-serial-connection-coonected-or-not-connected)

---

I would not be using `Serial.readString()` personally. How do you know where the string starts and ends? Just check for three "A" in a row.

Like this:

```C++
const unsigned long MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 10UL * 1000;  // 10 seconds
const byte LED = 7;

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  while (!Serial) ;  // wait for Serial to become active
  Serial.println ("Starting");
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
}  // end of setup

unsigned long lastMessage;
unsigned int countOfA;

void processInput ()
{
  while (Serial.available ())
  {
    char c = Serial.read ();
    if (c == 'A')
      countOfA++;
    else
      countOfA = 0;
    // do something with the data
  }  // end of while loop
}  // end of processInput

void loop ()
{
  if (Serial.available ())
  {
    lastMessage = millis ();  // remember when we last got input
    processInput ();  // now handle the input
  }  

  if (millis () - lastMessage >= MESSAGE_TIMEOUT)
  {
    countOfA = 0;
  }

  // warn if no keepalive received
  if (countOfA >= 3) 
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  else
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);

}  // end of loop
```

Note that this will fail (ie. it will light the LED) if it gets something other than "A" which would include newlines, etc.

What it does it count the number of times it gets the letter "A". If it gets something else it resets the count. If 10 seconds elapse without receiving something, the count resets.

Comment: It doesn't work though.

Comment: Well, it does, because I tested it. :P The words "doesn't work" do have a rather enraging quality (we hear them so often). Does the LED stay on? Stay off? Not go off after you type "AAA"? Not go on after a time-out? What Arduino are you using? Try to give details here.

Comment: Did you try from the console, or executed a py file? It works only from the console for some reason, like few others have experienced as well. I'm using a Nano.

Comment: What console? I am using the Arduino serial monitor. Make sure you get the baud rate right, I always use 115200 which is what I had in the code in my answer. I don't know why people limit themselves to 9600 baud.

Comment: The Python console. Issue is with Python, not Arduino

Comment: check the reference to [serial.write](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write) - if i understanding it right you have to manually add a Line-ending to your string...
and additionally if i remember correctly it could have to do with permission of your py file..