# Serial.readString() - how does it work exactly?

Tags: serial, python

Someone posted a solution for a problem I had which used Serial.read() .Why doesn't readString() seem to work though? From the docs it seems it reads the data as a String object which would make things a bit cleaner.

But here's my Python code:

```
import serial

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com7', 9600, timeout=0)

while True:
    arduinoSerialData.write('ALIVE\r\n')
```

And Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.readString() == "ALIVE") {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
}
```

If this was right, the green LED on the Arduino would light up when the Python program would run, but it doesn't. What is Serial.readString() expecting that it doesn't get?
I even tried `if (Serial.readString().startsWith("ALIVE"))` instead, as well as `arduinoSerialData.flush()` before `arduinoSerialData.write()`

Comment: All of your five questions so far seem to be about your issue with Python, and detecting if your USB connection is alive. They are just variations on a theme. Does reading work? Does writing work? Are there separate transmit and receive buffers? How does `readString` work? For example: [Pyserial serial.write() doesn't work](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/pyserial-serial-write-doesnt-work). I suggest you stick to one thread and work through your issues with the help of people who are genuinely trying to help you.

Comment: Nick, I'll suggest you "unstick" from me and get over the fact that I cross-posted before. Here's what happened: I had an issue and didn't know what was causing it, by experimenting for hours I wrongly deduced that the issue was reading and writing not working together properly, while it turns out it was me not understanding how readString() works. I have an eureka moment that the problem could be how readString() worked instead, and by asking it turned out to be the case. Answer below genuinely helped me. Monitoring my activity and bugging me continuously didn't, nor it seems ethical. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, these are separate questions (this one and the previous one). This is a Q&A site, as far as I know it's suggested to stick to one question per topic. Sticking to one thread per *issue* might be a good idea for forums.

Comment: I am not *monitoring* your activity. New questions are automatically shown to me (as to every visitor to the site). However if you prefer I do not respond to any future questions of yours I can certainly do that. It is hardly unethical to respond to further questions, and indeed the site encourages moderation by its users. Moderation being detecting cross-posts, poor quality posts, that sort of thing. However I am sure that others can achieve that if I do not.

Comment: I thought you understood what I meant... I think you noticed that I accepted one of your answers to one of the questions. Answers are welcome, criticizing me for making similar posts over and over again isn't very nice. I cross posted one of the questions, and you haven't gotten over it. Someone else even pointed out that one of my latest questions was different to another one you claimed to be the same, again.  I personally have nothing against cross posting, some people only visit Stack, some only visit the forums, but if it's against the rules, okay, I won't do it. And I'm not, anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readString()` will read characters from the serial (or other Stream) device until a timeout occurs.  That timeout is, by default, 1 second.  It is only appropriate to use `readString()` if your data is arriving in chunks with a minimum time between each chunk.

It is more appropriate to use `readStringUntil()` which will read characters from the serial device until *either* it times out, *or* it receives a certain character.  It is most common to use either the line feed (`\n`) or carriage return (`\r`) characters as the end of string marker.  You must, of course, ensure that your sending program sends the string terminated in the right way.

However, that all said, you really should avoid using String objects when possible, since the constant creation and destruction of temporary objects all over the place can make a real mess of your heap.

It is far better to learn to use character arrays and fill them using `Serial.read()`.  A tutorial I wrote for that is here:

- http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino

Comment: Thank you. It's about time I also learned what the timeout is. Is there some quetion/answer about that here already? The Pyserial docs don't seem to mention that. Don't know what "heap" is either.

Comment: The timeout is a function of the arduino's reading, not the PySerial's transmitting.  The heap is an area of memory in the Arduino that is used to dynamically allocate space for variables.

Comment: Thanks. So timeout is the delay between all the Serial.read() functions in the Arduino code? Sorry, just don't want to start a topic for something small like this.

Comment: @LeoErvin The timeout is how long readString waits to receive a character on the serial port before it decides that there are no more to receive. If more than 1 second passes without it having received a character then it finishes reading and returns whatever it has managed to get up until then.  It does mean that there will be *at least* a 1 second delay in your program while it waits for characters to arrive.

Comment: @LeoErvin If you send one character every 900ms then it will never finish, because it never reaches 1 second while waiting for the next character.  If you send 30 characters together, then don't send anything for more than one second, then `readString()` will wait for 1 second after the last character has been received and then return those 30 characters as a string.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It seems if I have a newline I also don't need to flush() from Python for some reason.

Comment: @LeoErvin It is called a *blocking* function, because it *blocks* the operation of the Arduino until it is finished. You can't do anything else for the entire time it's waiting for those characters to come in.  Far from desirable.

Comment: But it seems if I set timeout to 0 (which is probably pointless here), then do readStringUntil('\n'), it works fine. Then again I'm only sending few characters.

Comment: @LeoErvin Not perfect.  If there is a slight delay between characters in your string then it will chop the string off at that point and return the first half, since it timed out, and then it will return the second half as a new string when it gets the terminator.  Better to use a non-blocking stateful system like in the link in the answer that will signal when it has got a full line for you to process, and otherwise just return and allow you to continue.l

Comment: Hm, why will it chop if there is no timeout?

Comment: @LeoErvin There is a timeout - 0ms.  It runs the read portion while the elapsed time is less than the timeout, so the elapsed time will never be less than 0ms since time doesn't run backwards, so it's an instant timeout if there is no character in the receive buffer for it. You're confusing "0ms timeout" with "infinite timeout". The two are complete opposite ends of the spectrum.

Comment: Doesn't that mean readStringUntil() should never read anything if timeout is set to 0?

Comment: @LeoErvin No, because it first attempts a read, and only if that failed does it check the timout.  Take a look in the file Stream.cpp in the Arduino core for the `int Stream::timedRead()` function to see how it works.

Comment: Well, I don't know C++ (only basic stuff to be able to code Arduino), but thanks for explaining. By attempting a read I suppose you mean reading one character, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer plus the explanations in the commments :)